# tikz macro, how to implement

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I would like to make macro blocks for control loop block diagram. My idea is to have PI controller and filter blocks like in picture, and to have the possibility to simply add in my diagram, but I can't do iti. I have tried \tikzstyle \tikzset without success. Any help is welcome.

[image]

Comment: Dear Marko, can you show what you (unsuccessfully) try so far? Otherwise this is question *do-it-for-me* which aren't popular here. Maybe look into http://www.texample.net/ can give you some idea or starting point, how to draw your scheme. For design of symbols for PI controller etc. can be handy small pictures `pic`.

Comment: Although connecting to `pic`s can be trickier. But they are much simpler to make than specialised nodes, for example.

Comment: @Zarko I don't want somebody do-it-for-me,. I was looking on the forum and I did not find anything. What I have tried it didn't even compile. When I will do it, I will publish here if nobody knows how to make a rectangle with a line inside.

Comment: Thank you, percusse that was the answer I was looking for, but I didn't find it.

Comment: If you've answered your own question, then please post your answer in the answer space. If you still have a question, could you clarify what it is? I'm a bit confused as the question has been edited but I think you're saying that you've got your answer. Answering your own question is perfectly fine. (Asking purely in order to answer usually not, with some exceptions, but answering when you're figured it out later is encouraged!)

Comment: @cfr I have corrected, I answered my question.

Comment: You could have answered the duplicate which was more relevant. People won't find these blocks from that saturation question,

Answer (score 5):

Thank you, for the dupliacte link help, anyway as promised I will publish my blocks. They are mede of several posts, I hope I didn't made a mess.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article} 
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}
    \begin{document}

        \tikzset{
            controller/.style = {draw, fill=blue!20, rectangle, minimum height=3.5em, minimum width=6em},
            subblock/.style= {draw, fill=blue!5, rectangle, minimum height=3.5em, minimum width=6em},
            pidblocks/.style = {draw, fill=green!5, rectangle, minimum height=3.5em, minimum width=6em, text width= 6em},
            sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=1.5cm, inner sep=0.15cm},
            input/.style = {coordinate},
            output/.style ={coordinate}
        }

        \tikzset{%
            saturation block/.style={%
                draw,
                path picture={
                    % Get the width and height of the path picture node
                    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}%
                    {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}
                    \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
                    % Scale the x and y vectors so that the range
                    % -1 to 1 is slightly shorter than the size of the node
                    \tikzset{x=\x*.4, y=\y*.4}
                    %
                    % Draw annotation
                    \draw [very thin] (-1,0) -- (1,0) (0,-1) -- (0,1); 
                    \draw [very thick] (-1,-.7) -- (-.7,-.7) -- (.7,.7) -- (1,.7);
                },
                append after command={\pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode}
                    node[above right] at (\mainnode.north west) {#1}%
                }   
            }
        }

        \tikzset{%
            Filt block/.style = {%
                draw, 
                path picture={
                    % Get the width and height of the path picture node
                    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}%
                    {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}
                    \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
                    % Scale the x and y vectors so that the range
                    % -1 to 1 is slightly shorter than the size of the node
                    \tikzset{x=\x*.4, y=\y*.4}
                    %
                    % Draw annotation
                    \draw [very thin] (-1,-1) -- (-1,1) (-1,-1) -- (1,-1); 
                    \draw [very thick] (-1.0, -1) arc  [x radius =1.9, y radius = 1.4, start angle = 180,  end angle = 90] ;
                },
                append after command={\pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode}
                        node[above right] at (\mainnode.north west) {#1}%
                }
            }   
        }

        \tikzset{%
            Pctrl block/.style={%
                draw, 
                path picture={
                    % Get the width and height of the path picture node
                    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}%
                    {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}
                    \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
                    % Scale the x and y vectors so that the range
                    % -1 to 1 is slightly shorter than the size of the node
                    \tikzset{x=\x*.4, y=\y*.4}
                    %
                    % Draw annotation
                    \draw [very thin] (-1,-1) -- (-1,1) (-1,-1) -- (1,-1); 
                    \draw [very thick] (-1,.4) -- (1,.4);
                },
                append after command={\pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode}
                    node[above right] at (\mainnode.north west) {#1}%
                }   
            }
        }

        \tikzset{%
            PIctrl block/.style={%
                draw, 
                path picture={
                    % Get the width and height of the path picture node
                    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}%
                    {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}
                    \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
                    % Scale the x and y vectors so that the range
                    % -1 to 1 is slightly shorter than the size of the node
                    \tikzset{x=\x*.4, y=\y*.4}
                    %
                    % Draw annotation
                    \draw [very thin] (-1,-1) -- (-1,1) (-1,-1) -- (1,-1); 
                    \draw [very thick]   (-0.9,-1) -- (-0.9, -0.2) -- (0.9,.4);
                },
                append after command={\pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode}
                    node[above right] at (\mainnode.north west) {#1}%
                }   
            }
        }

        \tikzset{%
            Difer block/.style={%
                draw, 
                path picture={
                    % Get the width and height of the path picture node
                    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}%
                    {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}
                    \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
                    % Scale the x and y vectors so that the range
                    % -1 to 1 is slightly shorter than the size of the node
                    \tikzset{x=\x*.4, y=\y*.4}
                    %
                    % Draw annotation
                    \draw [very thin] (-1,-1) -- (-1,1) (-1,-1) -- (1,-1); 
                    \draw [very thick] (-0.9,-1) -- (-0.9, 0.6);
                },
                append after command={\pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode}
                    node[above right] at (\mainnode.north west) {#1}%
                }               
            }
        }

        \tikzset{%
            Integ block/.style={%
                draw, 
                path picture={
                    % Get the width and height of the path picture node
                    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}%
                    {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}
                    \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
                    % Scale the x and y vectors so that the range
                    % -1 to 1 is slightly shorter than the size of the node
                    \tikzset{x=\x*.4, y=\y*.4}
                    %
                    % Draw annotation
                    \draw [very thin] (-1,-1) -- (-1,1) (-1,-1) -- (1,-1);  
                    \draw [very thick] (-1,-1) -- (1, 1);
                },
                append after command={\pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode}
                    node[above right] at (\mainnode.north west) {#1}%
                }               
            }
        }   

        \tikzset{%
            Limit block/.style={%
                fill = none, 
                path picture={
                    % Get the width and height of the path picture node
                    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}%
                    {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}
                    \pgfgetlastxy\x\y
                    % Scale the x and y vectors so that the range
                    % -1 to 1 is slightly shorter than the size of the node
                    \tikzset{x=\x*.4, y=\y*.4}
                    %
                    % Draw annotation
                    \draw [thick] (-1,1) -- (-0.8, 0.5) -- (0.8,0.5) -- (1,1);
                    \draw [thick] (-1,-1) -- (-0.8, -0.5) -- (0.8,-0.5) -- (1,-1);
                },
                append after command={\pgfextra{\let\mainnode=\tikzlastnode}
                    node[above right] at (\mainnode.north west) {#1}%
                }               
            }
        }           

            %\begin{figure}[!h]
            %    \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, scale=0.8, node distance=3cm,>=latex', 
            every node/.style={transform shape}]      
            % We start by placing the blocks
            %\node [PICtrl={1}]
            \node [input, name=input1] {};
            \node [sum, right of=input1] (sumofinputerror) {}; 
            \node [Pctrl block = {$K_p$}, minimum size=1cm, right= 5cm of sumofinputerror, yshift=1.5cm] (kp) {};
            \node [Integ block = {$T_i$}, minimum size=1cm, right = 5cm of sumofinputerror, yshift=-1.5cm] (ki) {};
            \node [Difer block = {$T_d$}, minimum size=1cm] at ($(kp)!0.5!(ki)$)(kd){}; 
            \node [sum, right = 2cm of $(kp.east)!0.5!(ki.east)$] (controlsum) {}; 
            \node [saturation block = {$\frac{d}{dt}|_{max}$}, minimum size=1cm, right of= controlsum] (antiwindup) {};
            \node [Limit block = {$I_{max}$}, minimum size=1cm, right = 0.5cm of controlsum] (limit) {};
            %\node[] at (antiwindup) {\windup};
            \draw [->] (input1) -- node[name=inputerror] {$y_{ref}(t)$} (sumofinputerror);
            \draw [->] (sumofinputerror) -| ($(sumofinputerror)!0.5!(kp.west)$)|-(kp.west);
            \draw [->] (sumofinputerror) -| ($(sumofinputerror)!0.5!(ki.west)$)|-(ki.west);
            % --- draw lines
            \draw [->] (sumofinputerror) -- (kd);
            \draw [->] (kd) -- (controlsum);
            \draw [->] (ki) -| node[pos=0.95]{$+$}(controlsum);
            \draw [->] (kp) -| (controlsum);
            \draw [->] (controlsum)--(antiwindup);
            \node[right= 3cm of antiwindup] (output){};
            \draw[->] (antiwindup) --node[pos=0.8](c){} (output);
            \draw[->] (c) |- ([yshift=-1cm]ki.south)-|node[pos=0.95](){$-$}(sumofinputerror);   % feedback line
            \node [PIctrl block = {$K_p,T_i$}, minimum size=1cm] at (0,-2) (prop) {};
            \node [Filt block = {$T_f$}, minimum size=1cm] at (0,2) (filter) {};
            \end{tikzpicture}   
            %\label{fig:torque_pid_block}
            %\caption{Individual pitch and trailing edge flap control block.}
            %\end{figure}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Can you add links to the posts you used? Not only does that attribute the code to the authors, it can be incredibly useful for people trying to figure out how to do the same kind of thing.